# Visual Studio Web Publish blocked at server Firewall port 8192?

Tags: web-deployment

I recently changed to a new firewall (WatchGuard) at my hosting center where my IIS server is located.  Since then I can not use web publish from my desktop Visual Studio Publish.  I understand that it uses Ports 80 and 8172. When I try "Validate Connection" from Publish Web it times out with "Could not connect to remote computer. Make sure Web Deploy..."

However, my firewall Traffic Monitor displays (IP numbers changed!)

```
2018-01-28 09:53:55 Deny 99.999.999.88 66.66.66.123 http/tcp 49869 80 0-External Firebox Denied 52 118 (Unhandled External Packet-00)  proc_id="firewall" rc="101" msg_id="3000-0148" tcp_info="offset 8 S 2401276867 win 8192"     Traffic
```

I don't know if the 'win 8192" is a port number?  But this is the traffic being denied at the time I try to Validate Connection.  Nothing changed on my Visual Studio username/password.  None of my Publish functions are working.

The WatchGuard Policy I set is to allow

```
  From 'my ip above' to 'server above' --> 10.10.10.10  tcp: 8172.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "win 8192" is referring to the TCP window size.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes reading ones own question leads to one' own answer.
In the WatchGuard I did not set up port 80 for this policy name.
It works when both 80 and 8172 are enabled.